# bad compile constant value on dictinary string values

Tags: c#, winforms, dictionary

i am trying to make a dictionary to convert from Binary to Hex, this is what i made:

```
private Dictionary<string, char> binaryCharacterTohex = new Dictionary<string, char>
        {
            {'0000', "0"},
            {'0001', "1"},
            {'0010', "2"},
            {'0011', "3"},
            {'0100', "4"},
            {'0101', "5"},
            {'0110', "6"},
            {'0111', "7"},
            {'1000', "8"},
            {'1001', "9"},
            {'1010', "a"},
            {'1011', "b"},
            {'1100', "c"},
            {'1101', "d"},
            {'1110', "e"},
            {'1111', "f"}
        };
```

but it keeps giving me "bad compile constant value" on every binary string value i put there (the 'XXXX' ones), anyone can help me ?

Comment: you used the wrong `string quote`, double quote not single quote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Single quotes are used in C# to indicate a character, and double quotes indicate a string. You have them backwards right now. Switch them all out and it should work, like so:

```
private Dictionary<string, char> binaryCharacterTohex = new Dictionary<string, char>
{
    {"0000", '0'},
    {"0001", '1'},
    {"0010", '2'},
    {"0011", '3'},
    {"0100", '4'},
    {"0101", '5'},
    {"0110", '6'},
    {"0111", '7'},
    {"1000", '8'},
    {"1001", '9'},
    {"1010", 'a'},
    {"1011", 'b'},
    {"1100", 'c'},
    {"1101", 'd'},
    {"1110", 'e'},
    {"1111", 'f'}
};
```

Comment: Thank you, this is teh chosen answer :)

Answer (score 1):

`'.'` creates a **character** literal.
Characters can only be a single character.

You want a **string** literal, with double quotes.

Answer (score 1):

You inverted `string` and `char` quotes.

`' '` defines a `char`, `" "` a `string`

You need to replace  `{'0000', "0"},` by  `{"0000", '0'},`

Answer (score 1):

Double quotes: `""` are used to encase strings.  Single quotes: `''` are used for characters.  Your compiler error means you've got them backwards in your code.  You need to make your code look like this:

```
private Dictionary<string, char> binaryCharacterTohex = new Dictionary<string, char>
        {
            {"0000", '0'},
            {"0001", '1'},
            //and so on
        };
```